# Fair job processing algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I've got a machine that accepts user uploads, performs some processing on them, and then returns the result. It usually takes a few minutes to process each upload received.

The problem is, a few users can upload a lot of jobs that basically deny processing to other users for a long time. I thought of just setting a hard cap and using priority queues, e.g. after 5 uploads in an hour, all new uploads are given a lower processing priority. I basically want to process ALL jobs, but I don't want the user who uploaded 1000 jobs to make everyone wait.

My question is, is there a better way to do this?

My goal is to minimize the time between the upload and the result being returned. It would be ideal if the algorithm could work in a distributed manner as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementation will vary widely depending on what these jobs are and how long they take and how varied the processing times are, as well as how likely there is to be a fatal error during the process.

That being said, an easy way to maintain an even distribution of jobs across users is to maintain a list of all the users who have submitted jobs. When you are ready to get a new job, rather than just taking the next job out of a random queue, cycle through the users taking the top job from each user each time.

Again, this can be accomplished a number of ways, I would recommend a map from users to their respective list of jobs submitted. Cycle through the keys of the map each time you are ready for a new job. then get the list of jobs for whatever key you are on, and do the first job.

This is assuming that each job is "atomic" in that one job is not dependent on being executed next to the jobs it was submitted with.

Hope that helps, of course I could have completely misunderstood what you are asking for.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable solution to me.

Comment: you should also store users in liked list so users who get first also get fist job done first. When users job is finished if have any jobs remove from list or put user on end of line.

Comment: good suggestion ralu. again these are things that depend on more specifics of the OPs actual situation. Throughput might be the primary interest, in which case they might not want to do this extra processing. But that would be a nice feature for fairness.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to roll-your-own. There is [Sun Grid Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Grid_Engine). An open-source tool that is built to do that sort of thing, and if you are willing to pay, there is [Platform LSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_LSF), which I use at work.

Answer (score 0):

What is the maximum # of jobs a user can submit? Can users submit 1 job a a time OR is it a batch of jobs?

So your algorithm would go something like this

```
If the User has submitted jobs Then
Check how many jobs per hour
If the jobs per hour > than the average Then
Modify the users profile to a lower priority
Else
Check Users priority level and restore
End If

If the priority = HIGH
process right away
Else If priority = MEDIUM
Check Queue for High Priority
If High Priority Found (rerun this loop)
Else Process
Else If priority = LOW
Check Queue for High Priority
If High Priority Found (rerun this loop)
Else Process
Check Queue for Medium Priority
If Medium Priority Found (rerun this loop)
Else Process
Process Queue
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a graph algorithm like Edmond's Blossom V to assign all users and jobs to a process. If a user can upload more then another user it would be more simplier for him to find a process. With the Blossom V algorithm you can define a threshold to not exceed the maximum process the server can handle.